# how to interpret /sys/bus/pci/devices/<device id>/resource<number>

Tags: linux, pci

i'm trying to figure out how to interpret the the `resource` and `resource<number>` files under `PCI` bus. Let's look at a specific example.

Here is what I get when I run `lspci -tvvv`

```
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma]
           +-01.0  Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
           +-01.1  Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE
           +-02.0  InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
           +-03.0  Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           +-04.0  InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Guest Service
           +-05.0  Intel Corporation 82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller
           +-06.0  Apple Inc. KeyLargo/Intrepid USB
           +-07.0  Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI
           \-0d.0  Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
```

When I run `tree /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:00\:00.0/` I get the following:

```
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:00.0/
├── broken_parity_status
├── class
├── config
├── consistent_dma_mask_bits
├── d3cold_allowed
├── device
├── dma_mask_bits
├── driver_override
├── enable
├── firmware_node -> ../../LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A03:00/PNP8390:00
├── irq
├── local_cpulist
├── local_cpus
├── modalias
├── msi_bus
├── numa_node
├── power
│   ├── async
│   ├── autosuspend_delay_ms
│   ├── control
│   ├── runtime_active_kids
│   ├── runtime_active_time
│   ├── runtime_enabled
│   ├── runtime_status
│   ├── runtime_suspended_time
│   └── runtime_usage
├── remove
├── rescan
├── resource
├── subsystem -> ../../../bus/pci
├── subsystem_device
├── subsystem_vendor
├── uevent
└── vendor
```

When I run `tree /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:00\:03.0` I get the following:

```
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:03.0
├── broken_parity_status
├── class
├── config
├── consistent_dma_mask_bits
├── d3cold_allowed
├── device
├── dma_mask_bits
├── driver -> ../../../bus/pci/drivers/e1000
├── driver_override
├── enable
├── irq
├── local_cpulist
├── local_cpus
├── modalias
├── msi_bus
├── net
│   └── eth0
│       ├── addr_assign_type
│       ├── address
│       ├── addr_len
│       ├── broadcast
│       ├── carrier
│       ├── carrier_changes
│       ├── device -> ../../../0000:00:03.0
│       ├── dev_id
│       ├── dev_port
│       ├── dormant
│       ├── duplex
│       ├── flags
│       ├── gro_flush_timeout
│       ├── ifalias
│       ├── ifindex
│       ├── iflink
│       ├── link_mode
│       ├── mtu
│       ├── name_assign_type
│       ├── netdev_group
│       ├── operstate
│       ├── phys_port_id
│       ├── phys_switch_id
│       ├── power
│       │   ├── async
│       │   ├── autosuspend_delay_ms
│       │   ├── control
│       │   ├── runtime_active_kids
│       │   ├── runtime_active_time
│       │   ├── runtime_enabled
│       │   ├── runtime_status
│       │   ├── runtime_suspended_time
│       │   └── runtime_usage
│       ├── queues
│       │   ├── rx-0
│       │   │   ├── rps_cpus
│       │   │   └── rps_flow_cnt
│       │   └── tx-0
│       │       ├── byte_queue_limits
│       │       │   ├── hold_time
│       │       │   ├── inflight
│       │       │   ├── limit
│       │       │   ├── limit_max
│       │       │   └── limit_min
│       │       ├── tx_timeout
│       │       └── xps_cpus
│       ├── speed
│       ├── statistics
│       │   ├── collisions
│       │   ├── multicast
│       │   ├── rx_bytes
│       │   ├── rx_compressed
│       │   ├── rx_crc_errors
│       │   ├── rx_dropped
│       │   ├── rx_errors
│       │   ├── rx_fifo_errors
│       │   ├── rx_frame_errors
│       │   ├── rx_length_errors
│       │   ├── rx_missed_errors
│       │   ├── rx_over_errors
│       │   ├── rx_packets
│       │   ├── tx_aborted_errors
│       │   ├── tx_bytes
│       │   ├── tx_carrier_errors
│       │   ├── tx_compressed
│       │   ├── tx_dropped
│       │   ├── tx_errors
│       │   ├── tx_fifo_errors
│       │   ├── tx_heartbeat_errors
│       │   ├── tx_packets
│       │   └── tx_window_errors
│       ├── subsystem -> ../../../../../class/net
│       ├── tx_queue_len
│       ├── type
│       └── uevent
├── numa_node
├── power
│   ├── async
│   ├── autosuspend_delay_ms
│   ├── control
│   ├── runtime_active_kids
│   ├── runtime_active_time
│   ├── runtime_enabled
│   ├── runtime_status
│   ├── runtime_suspended_time
│   └── runtime_usage
├── remove
├── rescan
├── reset
├── resource
├── resource0
├── resource2
├── subsystem -> ../../../bus/pci
├── subsystem_device
├── subsystem_vendor
├── uevent
└── vendor
```

What are resources, i.e. `resource`, `resource0`, `resource2`? Are those BAR registers? If they are then a number in the name, i.e. 2 in `resource2` would mean BAR2. In this case what does `resource` represent?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Here’s some documentation.](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs-pci.txt)

Comment: @DanielB It says that `resource0..N` means `PCI resource N`. Do you know what is meant by `PCI resource`? Does anyone?

Comment: Not really, sorry. The only other thing I found is [this Stack Overflow q/a](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23669934/1025421). I can’t check whether that’s correct, however.

Comment: Is it answered ? what does the number means ?